# MySQL strange behavior

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, innodb

**DB Config**

- DB version: 8.0.23
- Isolation Level: REPEATABLE READ

I found a strange behavior in the locking mechanism and I'm trying to understand the difference between 2 flows.

***Flow 1:***

Imagine you have 2 connections that operates in parallel:

Connection1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO my_table (id,name) VALUES (101,'test');
```

Connection2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @id = (SELECT id FROM my_table where id = 101);
```

**NOTE:**

- In this flow (Flow 1) connection1 locks the row that have id=101 and connection2 will wait until connection1 will close the transaction.

***Flow 2:***

Imagine you have 2 connections that operates in parallel:

Connection1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO my_table (id,name) VALUES (101,'test');
```

Connection2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @id = NULL;
SELECT id INTO @id from my_table where id = 101;
```

**NOTE:**

- In this flow (Flow 2) connection1 locks the row that have id=101 and connection2 will **NOT** wait for connection1 to close the transaction (We will just get NULL because of the isolation level).

So I'm trying to understand what is the difference between these 2 flows
Why connection2 wait when using "SET" but doesn't wait when using "SELECT ... INTO ..."

FYI - For some reason it seems that using "SET" this way also locks the table (Flow1)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See e.g. [In MySQL Why does setting a variable from a select acquire a lock when using read uncommitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13151837) and the discussion in the bug report (which suggests the workaround you found too.)

Comment: If `Id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, why are you specifying the value?

Comment: With default isolation mode and no `FOR UPDATE`, conn 2 cannot see 101 until conn 1 Commits.